# different sorting tag cloud in mysql

Tags: mysql

my name is John and I am newbie in mysql.

I have a 3 tables: user, genre, usergenre.

1. I want to get a table with most popular genres.
2. And table with the users which are with most popular genres.
3. And table with the users which are with %my genre name% genre (ordered by genre usage)

Which sql requests I should use for it?

thanks!

---

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` longtext NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `usergenre` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `genre_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `usergenre_genre_id` (`genre_id`),
  KEY `usergenre_user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `usergenre_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `usergenre_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genre` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
CREATE TABLE `genre` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: There are plenty of good mySQL tutorials online that should lead you to a quick answer. Come back when you have a focused question and you're stuck after doing your basic research.

Answer (score 1):

for the first:

```
SELECT `t1`.`name`, COUNT(`t2`.`id`) AS x FROM `genre` AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `usergenre` AS t2 ON (`t1`.`id` = `t2`.`genre_id`) 
GROUP BY `t1`.`name` ORDER BY COUNT('x') DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your questions correctly:

1.Returns 10 most popular genres

```
select g.id, g.name, count(*) popularity 
from genre g, usergenre ug 
where g.id=ug.genre_id 
group by g.id, g.name 
order by popularity desc 
limit 10;
```

2.Returns users of the 10 most popular genres

```
with popularGames as (select ug.genre_id gid, count(*) c
    from usergenre ug 
    group by ug.genre_id
    order by c desc
    limit 10    
)
select u.id, u.username
from user u, usergenre ug 
where ug.genre_id in (select p.gid from popularGames p)
and ug.user_id=u.id
group by u.id, u.username;
```

3.Users for a specified genre ordered by the times the user uses the genre.

```
select u.id, u.username, count(*) usage
from user u, usergenre ug, genre g
where u.id=ug.user_id
and ug.genre_id=g.id
and g.name='SomeGenreName'
group by u.id, u.username
order by usage desc;
```

Comment: second example doesn't works. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'popularGames as (select ug.genre_id gid, count(*) c from usergenre ug group by u' at line 1

Comment: Looks like mysql does not support WITH (D'oh!) http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16244 However, I think you should have a good starting point and be able to implement it yourself in a mysql-conform way.